# How to show array element through timer

Tags: android

I have a String type array. I want to show each element in a TextView after a little time slice that means after certain time the element of array is showing in a TextView again and again. So I am using timer, but it is showing only last element of array. Please solve my problem as soon as possible.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    try {
                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, headerChild, expListView);
                        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                        int j=0, k=1;
                         if (prog.isShowing()) {
                                prog.dismiss();
                                expListView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                                String af="";
                                String cf="";


                                for(int i=0; i<breakstore2.length; i++){

                                    cf=breakstore2[j];
                                    af= breakstore2[k];

                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                    public void run() {

                                        marquee.setText("Breaking News :" + af);
                                        marquee.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),h_nextpage2.class);
                                                mainIntent.putExtra("listitem", cf);
                                                startActivity(mainIntent);

                                            }
                                        }); 

                                    }
                                }, DISPALY_LENGTH);
                                j=j+2;
                                k=k+2;
                                }

                            }

                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }               
             }       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is updating the UI faster than you wanted...what you can do is that you can create an `IntentService` and send that service the data that need to be put on your screen.

Create `Messenger` in your main activity where you need to update the UI and also create an `Handler` in the same. And from your `AsyncTask` post the updates to the intentService in that you can delay the updation by sleeping the intentServices' `thread` and then sending a message to the messenger on the main activity containing the data which you need to show (in your case breaking news) which in turn will do the updation for you.

Comment: Please give some example or elaborate the same, I am unable to  understand it completely. Thanks.

Comment: When you update using your code ,the code executes so fast that you are not able to see the previous updates. So you only see the last element from the array on the screen. Now to slow down the rate of updation rather than from there itself send someone else the data to update the UI periodically coz if you were to sleep/wait in that method then your main thread gets blocked so UI may feel laggy. Hence the above solution.